# I have changed indentation from 4 spaces to 2, why does it still show warnings?

Tags: python, pycharm

Here are my screenshots from pytcharm

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would you change from four spaces to two? Two isn't a multiple of four, and PEP 8 specifies that indentation should use four spaces.

Comment: You should use four spaces. Nonetheless, Alt + Enter on the marked warning text -> disable inspection should do the trick.